# Chrome won't play mp3 files?

Tags: google-chrome, cross-browser, get, mp3, httprequest

There's something very weird on my server- chrome won't play mp3 files on it.

for example, when chrome is pointed to an mp3 file on first server: http://tinyurl.com/czqfw5a - it won't play. When I place the same file on my second server: http://tinyurl.com/cju4yg4 -  it works fine.

I checked http response headers, on both servers it looks fine- mime type is set correctly.

The problem happens only with chrome. ff / ie work fine.

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: The GET request failed on the first server : `[xi3.mp3
/jdd/public/ct/pinyinaudio | GET | (failed) | Pending | Other | 13B / 0B | 369ms / 0.0 days]`

Comment: A 13bytes request, versus a 222bytes on the second server.

Comment: @samsamX, yes I saw that. However I can't understand why. It's only on Chrome. wget gets this file perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:
I downgraded apache to 2.2.17 - and all of a sudden things started to work.
No idea why, but probably something in the new version of apache manifests the mp3 playing bug at chrome. .

Answer (score 3):

**Short story**, it's this bug: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=110309

**Long story** is in the way it works, Chrome asks for the MP3 file, cancels out that request (cause it doesn't want to download), then sends out another request asking for streaming.

I tested a few times with WireShark. On one occasion it didn't close the connection and kept on sending packets, never actually responding to the second request. On other occasions I've even got a `HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified`.

Comment: Grigore, this is the same mp3 file on 2 different servers. On one servers chrome plays it, on another chrome does not. Any idea why that bug isn't happening on 2nd server? btw, I think the 304 is because of the expiry / etag.

Comment: Just by examining behavior I can't tell. Run a `phpinfo()`, see what modules your Apache is running, see changelog from 2.2.17 to 2.2.22... etc. There's a lot of work.

Answer (score 1):

I had to post here because I had the same problem. I realized that in Chrome, if you have the same mp3 file being served in two different tabs, the second tab will not load the mp3 file. It took me a while to realize that I had two tabs open. When I closed the one the other loaded fine. I hope I help some people out there that made the same stupid mistake as me lol

Answer (score 0):

Methinks it is a flash problem. at least on Chrome Version 32.0.1700.77 which i believe is still 32 bit and the latest [required] flash plugin is 64bit.