# HTTP GET Range (partial content)

Tags: http, google-chrome, range

my server can send all file, and part of file.

example of problem file.

```
<pre>
http://scir.bz/z/GOOD%20TO%20GREAT.mp3
</pre>
```

so, mozilla can play these audio file, and when we will move on timeline, mozilla plays it from a middle.
but google chrome can't do it. and I can't understand, why?

Example http conversation

mozilla -- server

```
GET /z/GOOD%20TO%20GREAT.mp3 HTTP/1.1

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: audio/mp3
Content-Length: 489986541
Last-Modified: Thu, 06 Mar 2014 18:02:55 GMT
Etag: "55a3ee720b5551b7fbb0b28318576ae9c9deb1cc1394128975"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

--jump on the middle

```
GET /z/GOOD%20TO%20GREAT.mp3 HTTP/1.1
Range: bytes=195002368-


HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Content-Range: bytes 195002368-489986540/489986541
```

--and I can continue to listen a file

chrome--server

```
GET /z/GOOD%20TO%20GREAT.mp3 HTTP/1.1

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: audio/mp3
Content-Length: 489986541
Last-Modified: Thu, 06 Mar 2014 18:02:55 GMT
Etag: "55a3ee720b5551b7fbb0b28318576ae9c9deb1cc1394128975"
Accept-Ranges: bytes

GET /z/GOOD%20TO%20GREAT.mp3 HTTP/1.1
Range: bytes=0-


HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Content-Range: bytes 0-489986540/489986541
```

--jump on the middle of afile

```
GET /z/GOOD%20TO%20GREAT.mp3 HTTP/1.1
Range:bytes=333119449-489986540

HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Content-Range: bytes 333119449-489986540/489986541
```

chrome canceled it and try

```
GET /z/GOOD%20TO%20GREAT.mp3 HTTP/1.1
Range:bytes=333119448-489986540

HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Content-Range: bytes 333119448-489986540/489986541
```

and yet

```
GET /z/GOOD%20TO%20GREAT.mp3 HTTP/1.1
Range:bytes=333119447-489986540

HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Content-Range: bytes 333119447-489986540/489986541
```

and yet

```
GET /z/GOOD%20TO%20GREAT.mp3 HTTP/1.1
Range:bytes=333119446-489986540

HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Content-Range: bytes 333119446-489986540/489986541
```

PS fiddler  shows no error in http

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps: [Chrome won't play mp3 files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10840260/chrome-wont-play-mp3-files)

The solution proposed is this:

> Found a solution: I downgraded apache to 2.2.17 - and all of a sudden things started to work. No idea why, but probably something in the new version of apache manifests the mp3 playing bug at chrome.